# R - Error in wordcloud "is_overlap" not resolved from current namespace (wordcloud)

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

Here's df I have after cleaning the corpus.

```
> wf
      term num
1  compani 341
2  product 122
3      may  79
4     risk  48
5   result  46
6   market  45
7     oper  45
8  foreign  42
9   servic  41
10  compon  39
```

I am trying to make wordcloud like this
`wordcloud(wf$term, wf$num)`

And here's an error I get:

```
Error in .Call("is_overlap", x11, y11, sw11, sh11, boxes1) : 
  "is_overlap" not resolved from current namespace (wordcloud)
```

Cannot imagine what's that.

Here's the result of dput(wf)

```
structure(list(term = structure(c(199L, 200L, 1012L, 801L, 528L, 
503L, 1010L, 1152L, 141L, 1177L), .Label = c("ability", "able", 
"absolute", "acceptable", "acceptance", "access", "accessories", 
"accidents", "accordingly", "account", "accounting", "accounts", 
"accrual", "accrued", "accrues", "achieve", "acquire", "acquired", 
"acquisitions", "across", "action", "actions", "activities", 
"activity", "acts", "actual", "addition", "additional", "additionally", 
"address", "addresses", "adequacy", "adequate",....), class = "factor"), 
    num = c(175, 159, 82, 79, 42, 39, 35, 34, 32, 32)), .Names = c("term", 
"num"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I do not get any error when I run your statement.  Please type `dput(wf)` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Did you edit the output, or did R put in that `....` ?

Comment: @G5W yes, it was to long to paste here

Comment: When you edit the structure like that,  we cannot cut and paste it.  Maybe you could use `wf2 = wf[1:10,]  ;  wf2$term = droplevels(wf2$term) ; dput(wf2)`

Comment: @G5W thank you! When I reload R session for the 10th time, the error just disappeared

Comment: I am glad that you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because "use.r.layout" has default value as FALSE . We need to change the wordcloud call as per below .

```
wordcloud(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62),use.r.layout = TRUE)
```

If we add use.r.layout = TRUE then the problem will rectify .